# Skype empty labels for some options from toolbar and other bugs on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, snap, skype

I have problems with **skype 8.89.0.403** on **ubuntu 22.04.01 LTS**
Sometimes when I am trying to open **tools** from toolbar I get this:

[Empty tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTmW5.png)

I have this bug with **File** and **View** too.

Also I have problem with main bar. Skype is the only application which have double icons:

[Double skype on main bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4n0M.png)

Some user on this portal suggest me that I should install skype using **snap**. I did it and nothing changed. I have this bug on debian version and snap too. Could someone give me a hint how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Issue is with Skype not an OS issue.

Comment: I am not sure I think ubuntu is the problem. I created post about it in skype community too: `https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/all/part-of-skype-toolbar-options-have-blank-content/1b4d39bd-e9f2-480e-b872-812dca55fe69`